# QGIS: Change attribute values from NULL to 0 for all attributes using Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, null

I have an attribute table where I have occurrences of NULL spread throughout in different attributes and features. How can I change NULL to 0 using Python for all attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky. @spatialthoughts has posted a recipe recently exactly for the intent on Twitter https://twitter.com/spatialthoughts/status/1290924804149665792

I post here a copy of the Twitter post content

For replacing NULL values. Use the coalesce() function. The following expression will replace NULL values in column "col1" with 0.

```
coalesce("col1", 0)
```

For all columns, you can use the following QGIS Python recipe to run in the Python PyQGIS console

```py
# Select a layer in the Layers panel and run the following
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# The following will replace NULL values with 0 in all columns
with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        attributes = f.attributes()
        new_attributes = [a or 0 for a in attributes ]
        f.setAttributes(new_attributes)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: That's excellent! Thank you!

Comment: Hey Thomas ! I tried to use the script you've provided but it replaces all values by '0' (even those that are not null) ! 
`layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        attributes = f.attributes()
        new_attributes = [0 for NULL in attributes ]
        f.setAttributes(new_attributes)
        layer.updateFeature(f)`

Do you have an idea about what I'm doing wrong please ?

Comment: Hey @Linda Keep ```new_attributes = [a or 0 for a in attributes ]
``` as shown in the example, it works.  ```new_attributes = [0 for NULL in attributes ] ``` will not work.